# PHP losing Session ID in PHPSESSID cookie when redirects

Tags: php, nginx, session, cookies, codeigniter-3

Hey guys I'm working on a `Codeigniter 3.1.11` project which is integrated with `Sentinel 2.0.8` and I'm facing an issue which I couldn't figure out!

Whenever I redirect to an external page (A payment gateway) on the callback `randomly` I lost the session. I was debugging and I realized that a new session has been created on the server while the previous one already exists and I mentioned the new one is set on my PHPSESSID cookie. If I go and change the set the value of `PHPSESSID` cookie with the previous one it shows login again.

My question is why it creates a new session while the previous one exists and why it doesn't reload the previous session. This is the part of the code which gets called when it comeback from payment gateway:

```
empty(session_id()) ? session_start() : '';
```

I'm running on a `LEMP Lando environment`.

Comment: did you try by commenting on it?

Comment: @M.Hemant yes. when I commenting it off I can't log in at all

Comment: gave it another try, by commenting it the session starts to get saved in the `$config['sess_save_path']` folder that I set. But it creates a new one when I come back from the redirect

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found the issue, this is actually happening only in Google Chrome due to the version 80+ update. Google updated the settings for SameSite cookie that cause this problem in the callback from the 3rd part (Cross-Domain) in my case, a payment gateway.

To be able to fix, this there are solutions available base on the version of PHP and your webserver.

Here is an example for PHP:
https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/php.md

Hope this helps! because it caused me to lose 3 days of my time!